# Big O relation between V and E in a connected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

In a connected graph, is it correct to say: |V| = O(|E|) ?

My intuition is that in a connected graph, |E| >= |V|-1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Big-oh notation gives an upper bound. For a connected graph we have `|E| >= |V|-1` like you said, so `|E|` is an upper bound for `|V|` and therefore we can say that `|V| = O(|E|)`.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Another related question: If G is Simple, we know that |V| <= E choose 2 ~= E^2. Can we also say that if G is simple then |V| = O(E) ?

Comment: I don't think so, it's `V = O(E^2)` for simple graphs, because you have `V <= E^2`, not `V <= E`.